# React-grid-layout - drag only on first div

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I implemented react-grid-layout with two elements. The thing is I have text in the first element and because it is draggable I can't copy the text from it because the element is moving.

I don't want to use a button to copy the text, but I was thinking maybe it is possible to decide which element can drag the whole square, is that even possible?

This is an example of the code I use:

```
<ResponsiveGridLayout
  className="layout"
  rowHeight={Number(height / 8) - 2}
  width={0.5}
  margin={[0, 0]}
>
<div
  key="a"
  data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 4 }}
>
  TEXT TEXT TEXT
  TEXT TEXT
</div>
<div
  key="b"
  data-grid={{ x: 0, y: 1, w: 1, h: 4 }}
>
  TEXT TEXT TEXT
  TEXT TEXT
</div>
</ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who may need this, just found the solution:

You should be able to target an element with a CSS selector in order to make it a drag handle. For example, if you add a class to your element like this:

```
<MyComponent>
  <div className="drag-handle"></div>
</MyComponent>
```

Then, you can pass the css selector using the draggableHandle prop like this:

```
<GridLayout draggableHandle=".drag-handle">
{props.children}
</GridLayout>
```